# Bootstrap 4 File Input not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using mdbootstrap(Bootstrap 4) free version in my php project. So it doesn't allow me to use input with type file. So I want use bootstrap 3 in that project for file upload functionality only.

Code Details are as follows:
I have created one template file. So in that I am rendering the required views at following line: `<?php require_once ("content/" . $content . ".php"); ?>`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php require 'common/cust_loader.php'; ?>
<?php require 'common/header.php'; ?>
<?php require 'common/popup.php'; ?>
<?php require_once ("content/" . $content . ".php"); ?>
<?php require 'common/footer.php'; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom scrollbar plugin -->
    <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){   
        $(window).on("load",function(){
            $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable=true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
            $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.axis="yx"; //enable 2 axis scrollbars by default
            $("#content-md").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"minimal-dark"});
            $(".all-themes-switch a").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $this=$(this),
                        rel=$this.attr("rel"),
                        el=$(".content");
                    switch(rel){
                        case "toggle-content":
                            el.toggleClass("expanded-content");
                            break;
                    }
                });         
        });
    })(jQuery);    
    </script>            
</body>
</html>
```

So in this file I have implemented mdbootstrap(bootstrap 4)
So for file upload I want to use bootstrap 3.

**Means in short I want use bootstrap 3 in bootstrap 4 code.**

Can anyone help me in this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you have copied components in the code from BS3 stylesheet and added in your BS4 stylesheet

Comment: Did you already try to use component from bootstrap3 in a file that you want to require with php ?

Comment: I can't do that. If I do like that it will change my websites appearance.

Comment: @Mile yes I have tried file upload in Bootstrap 3. But in mdbootstrap it doesn.t allow me to use file input.

Comment: @Shashikant, MDB's file input is a premium component which isn't available in MDB Free. Source: https://mdbootstrap.com/components/inputs/

Answer (score 0):

Material Design for Bootstrap 4

```
<form>
  <div class="file-field">
    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <span>Choose file</span>
        <input type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
       <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload your file">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Bootstrap 3 - input file form

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
  <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
  <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
</div>
```

What happens when you try it with one of these two solutions? Do you have some error message in console?